# How to flush Winston file logger

Tags: node.js, logging, flush, winston

If I set up a console logger and file logger, log some text and then quit with ctrl+c, the console logger displays all the logged text and the file logger only some of it.

Is it possible to flush the log to file when the process is terminated?

My configuration is as follows:

```
winston.remove(winston.transports.Console)
       .add(winston.transports.Console, {
            colorize: true,
            level: 'info',
            timestamp: true
        })
       .add(winston.transports.DailyRotateFile, {
            filename: 'mylog.log',
            json: false,
            level: 'debug',
            timestamp: true,
            maxsize: 10 * 1024 * 1024,
            maxFiles: 10
       });
```